# Where to define which key value is used in environment variables

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables

I have an application where I have an `application.properties` file with some sensitive data. I put those key value pairs for e.g. DB.USER.DEV and DB.USER.PROD in git to variables. After I set those pairs I use them like this in my `application.properties` file: `${DB.USER.DEV}` & `${DB.USER.PROD}`. Where can I define it which one has to be used when it's needed for `dev` or when for `prod` build.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to try to not make your app aware of the environment related settings. In your case I would have env. variable `DB_USER` and set appropriate values for that variable in a specific environment. For example on prod. you set prod. DB users username as a value for `DB_USER` env. variable and the same for dev. environment.

Nevertheless, you can still do it your way if you use [spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). You can have `application-<profile>.yaml[properties]` file which will use specific environment variable.